# Какую функцию использовать для подстановки значений в строку запроса?

Tags: php

Как сделать тоже самое на PHP?

```
`API_URL = "https://api.similarweb.com/v1/website/{site}/" \
          "total-traffic-and-engagement/visits?api_key={api_key}" \
          "&start_date={start_date}" \
          "&end_date={end_date}" \
          "&main_domain_only=false" \
          "&granularity={granularity}".format(
    site='cnn.com',
    api_key=MY_API_KEY,
    start_date="2017-09",
    end_date="2017-10",
   granularity="monthly"
)`
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду для подстановки переменных вместо `{param}`?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: А у вас данные, которые выше, они в виде строки?

Comment: Да, в виде строк.

Comment: Последний вопрос, `{value}` должно соответствовать своему названию? `$value`?

Comment: да, должно соответствовать

Comment: А если не будет переменной какой-то оставлять так же?

Comment: все переменные обязательны, будет валидация данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, как вариант с помощью `eval`:

```
$string = 'API_URL = "https://api.similarweb.com/v1/website/{site}/" \
          "total-traffic-and-engagement/visits?api_key={api_key}" \
          "&start_date={start_date}" \
          "&end_date={end_date}" \
          "&main_domain_only=false" \
          "&granularity={granularity}".format(
    site="cnn.com",
    api_key=MY_API_KEY,
    start_date="2017-09",
    end_date="2017-10",
   granularity="monthly"
)';

$site = 'test.ru';
$api_key = 'superkey';

$start_date = 'ONE';
$end_date = 'TWO';

$granularity = 'variable';

preg_match_all('#\{(.*?)\}#', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $m) {
    eval('$string = str_replace($m[0], $'.$m[1].', $string);');
}

echo $string;
```

В результате данные в формате `{параметр}` заменяются на значение переменной `$параметр`

В итоге получаем такую строку:

```
API_URL = "https://api.similarweb.com/v1/website/test.ru/" \
          "total-traffic-and-engagement/visits?api_key=superkey" \
          "&start_date=ONE" \
          "&end_date=TWO" \
          "&main_domain_only=false" \
          "&granularity=variable".format(
    site="cnn.com",
    api_key=MY_API_KEY,
    start_date="2017-09",
    end_date="2017-10",
   granularity="monthly"
)
```

**UPD**: Решение чуть попроще:

```
$string = str_replace('"', '\"', preg_replace('#\{(.*?)\}#i', '\$$1', $string));
eval('$string = "'.$string.'";');

echo $string;
```

***Или*** вместо функции `str_replace` возьмем `addcslashes` для экранирования кавычек:

```
eval('$string = "'.addcslashes(preg_replace('~\{(.*?)\}~i', '\$$1', $string), '"').'";');

echo $string;
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Евгений, добавил еще один вариант попроще, рассмотрите